# Why my this formula doesn't satisfy the formula of volume of sphere?

Tags: integration, geometry, systems-of-equations, spheres

I've defined the function which returns a volume of sphere as a radius value given.

$f(a):=2\int_{0}^{a}\pi*r^{2}*dr$

I thought that above function is correct but actually it is not correct.

The return value of the above function is $\frac{2\pi a^{3}}{3}$

The $2$ at the leftmost of the function represents of a double of volume of hemisphere.

Can anyone tell my why this function is not working?

Comment: The surface area of a sphere of radius $r$ is $4 \pi r^2$.

Comment: I know it but I wanted to deduce the formula using a area of circle.

Comment: You seem to be decomposing the hemisphere into some circles, with the idea of getting the volume of the hemisphere by integrating a term with the area of a circle.  But the radius of the circles doesn't vary ln the way you apparently thought (the circle radius goes from $0$ to $a$  but not in the way you've expressed it).

Comment: Now that the comment by @hardmath and the answer by eordo have shown why your calculation doesn't give the volume of a sphere, you might want to go back and check that you have actually computed the volume of a double cone.

Comment: @hardmath Can you please elaborate a bit more? Why doesn't the integral sum up $\pi r^2$ from $0$ to $a$? Thanks

Comment: @MangoPizza:  The integral in the body of  the Question *does* sum up $\pi r^2 dr$ over $r\in [0,a]$.  However that gives the volume of a cone, not the volume of the hemisphere.  Working through the Answer posted by eordo will illuminate that for you.  It's a standard "solid of rotation" volume problem.  (Basically the radius of the "sliced" circles does not vary linearly with distance from the center.)

Comment: @hardmath If i understand correctly. When doing standard integration, say of $f(x)$ from $2$ to $5$, the $x$-axis values from $2$ to $5$ vary linearly i.e. they (all the values from $2$ to $5$) are equally spaced. But in a sphere, the radius-es is not equally spaced, so the integration does not given the correct value. Am I right? Thanks

Comment: @MangoPizza:  I think you probably understand.  If we let $x$ measure distance from the center of the sphere, then the radius of the circular slices is a nonlinear function of $x$.  The notation in eordo's Answer uses $y$ for the radius of the circular slices and $r$ for the radius of the sphere (so $x$ goes from $0$ to $r$ for the hemisphere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a radius $r$, consider the graph of the semicircle given by $y = \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$ for $x \in [-r, r]$.
Rotate this graph about the $x$-axis, and you will find the volume of the resulting sphere as an integral.

Comment: Do you mean $r^2$?

Comment: Yes it should be $r^2$, thanks for the correction